# vmware enlarging space for linux

Tags: linux, vmware, diskspace

Its maybe stupid question but how can i enlarge my linux machine from 20 to 40gb? i need to increase my / space. I made it on vmware and its says 40gb now but if i make :

```
df -h

Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/zabbix-root   19G   17G  789M  96% /
udev                     489M  4.0K  489M   1% /dev
tmpfs                    200M  276K  199M   1% /run
none                     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                     498M     0  498M   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda1                228M   25M  192M  12% /boot
```

or

```
fdisk -l

Disk /dev/mapper/zabbix-root: 20.1 GB, 20124270592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2446 cylinders, total 39305216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/zabbix-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/zabbix-swap_1: 1069 MB, 1069547520 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 130 cylinders, total 2088960 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

i still se only 20gb... How can i mount another 20gb?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your distribution, probably something like that:

```
reboot or echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/rescan
```

Now that Linux is aware of the disk size change, use pvextend to extend you PV. 
 
Using vgdisplay, make sure that you have free space on your VG. 
Extend your LV using lvextend and finally, use resize2fs to change your FS.